# Blender .fbx shows up incorrectly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender

I made `FPS` hands and gun in Blender but when I export it on Unity as `.fbx`, it shows up incorrectly. Positioning of the gun is wrong finger is stretched ect. I applied all the transforms to the objects in `Blender` but it didn't fix it.

[This is `Blender` screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVNQ7.jpg)

[And this is `Unity` screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p0VR.jpg)

Comment: have you tried to import the model of the gun, check if its all correct, and then check the body model? Also check for open faces, non-connected vertices, etc https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/cleanup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redid everything and it worked. I couldn't manage to identify the problem. I did everything as same as the last time. At the end of the day, it fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried importing the model multiple times? most likely there were errors while importing the model, please try again

Comment: Yeah I tried it but didn't work